# Где взять файл libintl.h для компиляции проекта в С++?

Tags: c++

Использую Code Blocks.
При компиляции проекта из исходников ( http://themanaworld.org/ ) вылезает ошибка:

```
src\utils\gettext.h|29|error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
```

В readme.txt сказано, что необходимо подключить:

```
* CMake >= 2.6      http://www.cmake.org/
* GNU gettext       http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/
* CVS               http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/ (needed to run autopoint)
```

Скачал GetText, но проблема в том, что там нет файла libintl.h
Подскажите, где его взять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://packetprotector.org/download/experimental/gettext/libintl.h

Comment: Не подскажешь, почему его в архиве с офиц. сайта нет?

Comment: Понятия не имею, если честно. Бывает.